# Automatic recompile using ngx-translate and angular cli

Tags: json, internationalization, angular-cli, ngx-translate

I am using `ngx-translate` in a project controlled by [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). I have my language strings in a json file - everything setup as by the ngx-translate documentation.

I include the json file via http, like the documentation notes

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {AppComponent} from './app';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This works well. However, if I update the json file, with new text strings. Angular CLI does not automatically pick up the change and reload the app. Also, if I manually reload the page, the changes are also not picked up - probably because everything is in memory.

How can I tell Angular CLI to watch for changes to the json file?

Do I need to eject the webpack config, and configure it manually? I would rather not do that, as many developers working on the project are not quite suited to mess directly in webpack config files.